# How to get user fiendly output from multiclass classification tensorflow based model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am building a multiclass classification model which would predict the disease based on 17 symptoms on the input. As an output, I receive an array with "zeroes" and "ones" (since I did one-hot encoding to make the model work).

I tried to do reverse label encoding to receive a sting label of the predicted disease as the final output but received an array of sting labels that does not look correct.  I feel like I did something wrong with the one-hot encoding part. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from keras.utils import np_utils

dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv') #source https://www.kaggle.com/itachi9604/disease-symptom-description-dataset

symptoms = dataset.drop('Disease',axis=1).fillna('Absent')
disease=dataset['Disease']

X = symptoms.values.astype(str)
y = disease.values.astype(str)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=101)

#One-hot encoding based on https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/
ordinal_encoder = OrdinalEncoder()
ordinal_encoder.fit(X_train)

X_train = ordinal_encoder.transform(X_train)
X_test = ordinal_encoder.transform(X_test)

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(y_train)
y_train = label_encoder.transform(y_train)
y_test = label_encoder.transform(y_test)

# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=17, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(41, activation='softmax'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=X_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=200,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1
          )

predictions = (model.predict(X_test[:1]) > 0.5).astype("int32")

predictions = label_encoder.inverse_transform(predictions.reshape(-1))

print(predictions)
###the Output I recieve: 
['(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo' 'AIDS'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo'
 '(vertigo) Paroymsal  Positional Vertigo']
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, can you explain this line please? 
`predictions = (model.predict(X_test[:1]) > 0.5).astype("int32")`

Comment: @roman_kat his line had to look this way initially **predictions = model.predict(X_test[:1])**  and its purpose was to make predication based on the model from the 1st row of X_test data. For some reason it was not working for me  but this one worked **predictions = (model.predict(X_test[:1]) > 0.5).astype("int32")**. - I found this at ML forum.

Comment: I think slice `[:1]` means [0, 1), so this slice only takes 1 row of X, if you want to start from row one and go to the end of an array the slice should be `[1:]`. So effectively you are only predicting one data point and this prediction is a vector of 41 values (as your output layer). How much data do you have? Predicting 41 class from 17 features is hard, you might want to increase your network size if the data volume permits

Comment: @roman_ka, you are right, `X_test[:1]` is 1 row of X that simulates a data entry that I need to predict a decrease out of one entry that consists of 17 symptoms, just as I need for the prediction.  The volume of my data is more the 4000 rows. I know that the model is yet to be optimized to be more accurate, I will do that later. For now, I just need proof that I can get a disease predication out of 1 entry with 17 symptoms...

Answer (score 0):

Just use `argmax()` to do a `onehot-encoding` inverse operation.

```py
predictions = label_encoder.inverse_transform(np.argmax(predictions, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have figured it out.
The issue was that I was using ordinal encoding for categorical values (symptoms) which were not ordinal.

The encoding option that works for my case is OneHotEncoder from Sklearn.

Thank you, guys, for your attention to this question anyway, since it inspired me to go on digging ...

Finally, my current solution looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder


dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv') #source https://www.kaggle.com/itachi9604/disease-symptom-description-dataset

X = dataset.drop('Disease',axis=1)
y=dataset['Disease']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=101)

X_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto',
                       drop='first', # to return k-1, use drop=false to return k dummies
                       sparse=False,
                       handle_unknown='error') # helps deal with rare labels

X_encoder.fit(X_train.fillna('Missing'))

X_train=X_encoder.transform(X_train.fillna('Missing'))
X_test=X_encoder.transform(X_test.fillna('Missing'))


y_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto',
                       drop='first', # to return k-1, use drop=false to return k dummies
                       sparse=False,
                       handle_unknown='error') # helps deal with rare labels

y_train = y_train.values.reshape(3690,1)
y_test = y_test.values.reshape(1230,1)


y_encoder.fit(y_train)


y_train=y_encoder.transform(y_train)

y_test=y_encoder.transform(y_test)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=391, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='softmax'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=X_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=600,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1
          )
#X_test[10:11] is for taking one sline of data of symptoms  per one disease
predictions = (model.predict(X_test[10:11]) > 0.5).astype("int32")

predictions = y_encoder.inverse_transform(predictions)

print(predictions)


##Output: 

array([['Acne']], dtype=object)
```